# how to change innerHtml by adding a integer value to element?

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml

I build a Scoreboard

what it does when someone click the +500 button it will add 500 to the value in the score board i.e it will add 500 to the value of p tag

```
   <div class="box"> 
 <h2>Teams</h2>
 <div class="score">
    <p id="p1" class="lead">230</p>
  </div>
  /div>
 <button id="b1">+500</button>
```

JavaScript for it

```
var myScore = document.getElementById("b1");
myScore.onclick = function () {
    var newScore = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
    var value = newScore + 500;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = value;
};
```

but this is showing me  **230500** instead of **730**. how to change my inner html value 230 in integer form ??

Comment: String + int = String. :)

Comment: dom contents are strings. and are ALWAYS strings. you need to parse the string back to an int first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right now, you're adding an integer to a string, so you're making a string concatenation.

Change

```
 var value = newScore + 500;
```

to

```
 var value = parseInt(newScore,10) + 500;
```