# Adding numbers instead of adding increment

Tags: javascript, increment

I have a small script that increments the number by the number in a given time period. If incrementing by one **value++** works, if I want to add another value of the type generated by the math.random function instead of adding, add to the existing value. How can I change this? I want the generated number to add to an existing value in innerHTML.

```js
document.getElementById("data-gen").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

nowResources = function() {
  document.getElementById("data-gen").innerHTML += Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  setTimeout(nowResources, 1000);
}

nowResources();
```

```html
<span id="data-gen" style="color: #da5cb2;"></span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change innerHtml by adding a integer value to element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264978/how-to-change-innerhtml-by-adding-a-integer-value-to-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You append numbers to a string. Convert your `innerHTML` to a number with `parseInt` and it'll work as you expecting.

```js
document.getElementById("data-gen").innerText = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

nowResources = function() {
  // parseInt( yourString, radix )
  const num = parseInt( document.getElementById("data-gen").innerText, 10 );
  document.getElementById("data-gen").innerText = num + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  setTimeout(nowResources, 1000);
}

nowResources();
```

```html
<span id="data-gen" style="color: #da5cb2;"></span>
```

But one downside is, that you are querying the DOM each time you want to change it. It's better to store your number outside of your timeout and use an interval like this:

```js
let num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

document.getElementById("data-gen").innerText = num;
nowResources = function() {
  num += Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  document.getElementById("data-gen").innerText = num;
}

setInterval( nowResources, 1000 );
nowResources();
```

```html
<span id="data-gen" style="color: #da5cb2;"></span>
```

This way you don't need to parse your number with each iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I thought that was about it, but as you can see, someone had to make me aware of it. I'll say your best for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

When you use + it takes as string and concatenate as a string, convert it to an integer using **`parseInt`**

```
  document.getElementById("data-gen").innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById("data-gen").innerHTML) + (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
```

**DEMO**

```js
document.getElementById("data-gen").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1)+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

nowResources = function() {
  document.getElementById("data-gen").innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById("data-gen").innerHTML) + (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
  setTimeout(nowResources, 1000);
}

nowResources();
```

```html
<span id="data-gen" style="color: #da5cb2;"></span>
```

Comment: Don't you think there is a duplicate out there as this is a really simple and probably often asked question?

Answer (score 1):

To keep the logic clear, just use a local variable to store the value, no need to backward converting via `parseInt` and weary (and expensive, and messy) DOM element methods dancing:

```
var value = 0;

function setValue(addValue) {
    value += addValue;
    document.getElementById("data-gen").innerHTML = value;
}

nowResources = function() {
  setValue(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1))
  setTimeout(nowResources, 1000);
}

nowResources();
```